# How to run an example Java Project I have downloaded from Jena?

Tags: java, jena

I'm still not that familiar with ontologies, and specially with Java. I have this project that I want to run so I can see how this Java Lib (Jena) works, but I don't know how to do It. Here is the files I have:

```
java
|--org
  |--apache
    |--jena
      |--example
       |--Base.java
       |--CheeseBase.java
       |--helloworld
        |--HelloWorld.java
       |--pizza
        |--PizzaSparqlNoInf.java
       |--streaming
        |--StreamRDFToConnection.java
resources
```

There is a main class in HelloWorld.java that I want to run, how to I do It? There are also some rdf and ttl files in the resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ would be good. You can browse and play with the code and create run configurations to see how the project runs. There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube for how to set these up with a Hello World project that should help you get started.